# How to convert bytes into string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, byte, python-unicode

I have a bytes and I want to convert it into string in python ?

These are the bytes that I want to convert:

```
b'\xfeD1\xc2B\xac\xf86Mx\xc1\x0e\xa4\xe2x\x0c,\xd4\x1a\xb1'
```

but I am not able to convert it into normal characters.

Also I am providing the above byte as input.

I had tried:

```
my_str = b'\xfeD1\xc2B\xac\xf86Mx\xc1\x0e\xa4\xe2x\x0c,\xd4\x1a\xb1'.decode()
print(my_str)
```

and the error that I am getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Mainproject.py", line 39, in <module>
    my_str = b'\xfeD1\xc2B\xac\xf86Mx\xc1\x0e\xa4\xe2x\x0c,\xd4\x1a\xb1'.decode()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfe in position 0: invalid start byte
```

**Edit:1**
This is the code i used to encode the text. Here i am trying to some pn sequence to encrypt an inputed text and the resultant output that i am getting is a byte.
Now i want to create another program that takes this byte as input and decode it into plain text.

```
from pylfsr import LFSR

# The initial state
state = [0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1]
# The LFSR polynomial use a primitive polynomail to get maximum period length
poly = [2,2,3,4,2]
l = LFSR(fpoly=poly, initstate =state)
print(l)
message = input().encode()
ciphertext = b""

# generate all LFSR sequence
allseq = l.runFullCycle()
seq = ""
seq_index = 0

# Convert LFSR bits into a string
for x in allseq:
    seq += str(x)
for counter in range(len(message)):
    ran_seq = seq[seq_index: seq_index+8]
    # Now encrypt by XOR convert to bytes and append to ciphertext
    # print(type(message[counter]),message[counter],type(ran_seq),ran_seq,int(message[counter]^int(ran_seq)))
    ciphertext += bytes([int(message[counter]) ^ int(ran_seq, 2)])
    # print(ciphertext)
    seq_index += 8  # Move sequence to Next byte

print(ciphertext)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `latin1` encoding but this have consequences of if these bytes are non latin characters you will end up with Mojibake character which seems to be the case in your situation. Can you say what kind of string this is?

```
my_str = b'\xfeD1\xc2B\xac\xf86Mx\xc1\x0e\xa4\xe2x\x0c,\xd4\x1a\xb1'
print(my_str.decode("latin1"))
```

EDIT: You are trying to decode encrypted `ciphertext` and get your text back un tacked which is what encryption try to prevent, To get your text back you will have to decrypt first then decode use this code:

```
from pylfsr import LFSR

state = [0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1]
poly = [2,2,3,4,2]
l = LFSR(fpoly=poly, initstate =state)
print(l)
message = input("Enter message to encrypt: ").encode()
ciphertext = b""

allseq = l.runFullCycle()
seq = ""
seq_index = 0

for x in allseq:
    seq += str(x)
for counter in range(len(message)):
    ran_seq = seq[seq_index: seq_index+8]
    ciphertext += bytes([int(message[counter]) ^ int(ran_seq, 2)])
    seq_index += 8  # Move sequence to Next byte

print(ciphertext)
ciphertext_file_name = "ciphertext"
with open(ciphertext_file_name, "wb") as out_file:
    out_file.write(ciphertext)

# Read ciphertext and decrypt it
with open(ciphertext_file_name, "rb") as in_file:
    ciphertext = in_file.read()
    seq_index = 0
    plaintext_again = b""
    for counter in range(len(ciphertext)):
        ran_seq = seq[seq_index: seq_index + 8]
        plaintext_again += bytes([int(ciphertext[counter]) ^ int(ran_seq, 2)])
        seq_index += 8  # Move sequence to Next byte
    print(plaintext_again.decode("latin1"))
```

Comment: Yes true I had tried and got Mojibake characters :(

Comment: @WOZNIK What language is this string ?

Comment: English , 'This is a plain text' <- this is string that i had encoded

Comment: @WOZNIK: The byte data shown in your question is not that plain text.

Comment: @WOZINIK can you edit your question with how you encoded this plaintext since this plain text seems to not relate to the byte string

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: @WOZINIK and this byte string is it  the ```ciphertext``` if yes, then this makes complete sense because the byte string is ```ciphertext``` decoding it will result in garbage you will have to decrypt first then decode so you will have to xor ciphertext with same key stream values first

Comment: Adding this into existing code will surely decrypt and decode it but i am trying to write the decryption code into another file Which means First i encrypt using my above code after which i will get an encrypted text as output then i am copy the encrypted text from console and given it as input to decryption code in another file this is a point where it's creating problem .

Comment: @WOZINIK edited the answer so you write ciphertext to file then read it back and decrypt it.

Answer (score 0):

`decode` converts `bytes` to `str`. `encode` converts `str` to `bytes`.

```
my_str = b'\xfeD1\xc2B\xac\xf86Mx\xc1\x0e\xa4\xe2x\x0c,\xd4\x1a\xb1'.decode()
```

Comment: I tried this but getting with an error that i had updatedin the ques.

Comment: The bytes you have do not represent a UTF-8 string, so there is no sensible way to convert it to one. How were those bytes created? If they were created using a different encoding, you can specify that in `decode(encoding='whatever')`

Comment: @martineau Using this didn't gave me any error but at the same time it also didn't decoded the right output :(